# about multiprocessing process

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I use process of multiprocessing in python2.7 to create too processes, as shown below:

```
p1 = Process(target=build_sql_s, args=(Scopes,))
p2 = Process(target=build_sql_o, args=(Orders,))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

`Scopes` and `Orders` are two `list var`, `build_sql_s` and `build_sql_o` are `functions`.
when I run this program, `cpu` for `p1` is `70%`, but cpu and memory for `p2` is `0%` all the time till `p1`'s work is done in a computer with `8 core`...
why? shouldn't the Process of multiprocessing used the different core of a computer?

Comment: I didn't follow you~ Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: How long is your list 'Orders' it might be that the work is done very quickly. Normally Process should use an other core. But you should give us more details about your code : Is your code in a if __main__ ?

Comment: yes, it's in a if main. and Scopes'size is hundreds of thousand and Orders‘size is almost four million. Is there any possibility that work about Scopes is done very quickly? but it still in the process list of top command..

Comment: What you say is that p2 starts when p1 terminates?

Comment: It turns out that p1 is done very quickly~ In the end of the program the top command shows all processes is taking 0% of the cpu and wait for the result of inserting data into mysql. Thank u ~

Comment: I mean p1 is quick enough to finish it's work and at the same time p2 is just going to start. because data of p1 to calculate is 100times less than p2's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used explicit `.start()` and `.join()` as you showed, but I have used `multiprocessing.Pool()` with satisfying results.  `Pool()` sets up a pool of worker processes, by default one per processor core, and then the `.map()` method puts them to work.  I suggest you give it a try.

Here's a simple program I just wrote to demonstrate the use of `multiprocessing.Pool().map()`.

Tested under Python 2.7 and Python 3.3.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def is_odd(n):
    return bool(n%2)

def hailstone(n):
    """
    Compute the Hailstone sequence, as described in:
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture
    """
    steps = 0
    while n > 1:
        steps += 1
        if is_odd(n):
            n = 3*n + 1
        else:
            n = n//2
    return steps


def slow(limit):
    steps = sum(hailstone(n) for n in range(limit))
    #print("n: {}  steps: {}".format(n, steps))
    return (limit, steps)

LIMIT = 2000

start = time.time()
results0 = [slow(n) for n in range(LIMIT)]
stop = time.time()
elapsed0 = stop - start

print("Single-threaded time: {:.2f} seconds".format(elapsed0))

# note we are including time to set up the Pool() in the elapsed time
start = time.time()
p = mp.Pool()
results1 = p.map(slow, range(LIMIT))
stop = time.time()
elapsed1 = stop - start

results1.sort()

print("Multiprocessing time: {:.2f} seconds".format(elapsed1))

assert results0 == results1
```

I see almost exactly a 4x speedup when running in the `multiprocessing.Pool()`.  Tested on an AMD FX-8350 (which has 4 "Bulldozer modules" internally).

Comment: Process is another way to use multi cores, what I thought is wrong at the beginning, It do use multi cores at the same time and I misunderstand what I saw. You are so kind I am glad to take your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Core selection and distrubution of processes is matter of OS, not your code. Multithreading doesnt mean u are separating your executed code to CPU's, also multiprocessing too in multiprocessing module..

Comment: I have tried multiprocessing within a Class(inherited from multiprocessing) and it works well. Is this the problem why my program cannot performance as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I see your problem right now.

You have to know that processors do not share the same memory. Thus when you create and start a new process giving it a (really) large list, the list is first copied. This may take a time ...

One possibility, even more if your data (= lists) are read-only is to use share memory. Have a look there : http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.sharedctypes 
with multiprocessing.Array